# Spring Security 5 + OAuth2 + Webflux : authorization success listeners

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, listener, spring-webflux

In '**Spring Security Reference**' page, section [5.11 Post Processing Configured Objects](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#post-processing-configured-objects) introduces the concept of an **ObjectPostProcessor** where we can configure a **filterSecurityPublishAuthorizationSuccess** property on **FilterSecurityInterceptor**.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
                    public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess(O fsi) {
                        fsi.setPublishAuthorizationSuccess(true); //1 This requires JavaX Servlet API
                        return fsi;
                    }
                });
    . . . 
}
```

In my case using this ObjectPostProcessor I'm able to log authorization success using an **ApplicationListener**.

```
package org.mycompany.security.reactive.logging;

    public class AuthorizationSuccessListener implements ApplicationListener<AuthorizedEvent> {
        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(AuthorizedEvent event) {
        
            // log journals
        
        }
    }
    . . .
```

Right now I'm migrating my application to use Spring Webflux (Reactive) instead of RestTemplate (Java Servlet API).

**The problem after migrating my code is:** the code from Spring Security page requires the Servlet API (error: The type javax.servlet.Filter cannot be resolved. ) on the line with my comment: //1.

The client code is a simple @RestController + @GetMapping using Spring WebClient.

Has anyone been through a situation like this or know another approach?

Comment: if you are looking for a 1 to 1 conversion then im guessing no, but you can try listening for authentication events https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/events.html or add a `authenticationSuccessHandler` and a `authenticationFailureHandler`

Comment: But I see the documentation you mentioned targets Servlet applications, right?

docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/

Comment: Did you you actually check the api in the code before writing that or did you just look at the docs and see ”servlet, then it doesn’t work” authenticateSuccess and authenticateFailureHandler both exist in webflux so please try before you comment

Comment: Yes, I tried the exactly code and it didnt't work. The class with @EventListener is never triggered. Probably because of the few events are targeted by DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher.

There's even a class in the documentation for setting a Default Event that doesn't seem to exist: GenericAuthenticationFailureEvent.